# Creating a scrollable JTable within a JPanel - won't show table data when using GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, layout-manager

I am trying to create a simple scrollable JTable with some arbitrary values and place it inside of a JPanel. I am experiencing some strange results where the JTable appears but shows only the column names and seems to squish the remaining rows. Also the table appears in the center of the panel and I would like it to be at the top.

```
        // Panel to hold our layer information
        JPanel layerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        layerPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        layerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.insets = new Insets(0,5,0,5);
        c.weightx = 1; c.weighty = 0.0;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.gridx = 0; c.gridy = 0;

        String[] columns = { "Show", "Layer" };
        Object[][] data = {{"x", "Layer1"},
                           {"x", "Layer2"}};

        // Construct our table to hold our list of layers
        JTable layerTable = new JTable(data, columns);
        layerTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(64);

        layerPanel.add(new JScrollPane(layerTable), c);
        frame.add(layerPanel);
```

[Link to photo of results](http://i1241.photobucket.com/albums/gg511/DynamicCast/ba901114.png)

Any help is appreciated, the code works when I use a GridLayout(1,0) instead of using the GridBagLayout so I have a feeling that I am using it wrong.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not setting any 'weight' in the Y axis, so your `JscrollPane` will not expand in that axis. You could use:

```
c.weighty = 1;
```

to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the `GridBagConstraints.weighty` to 1

```
c.weighty=1;
```